# Can ginger grown in a garden landscape be used as an edible spice?

Tags: edible, ginger, spices

Can flowering gingers like White Butterfly [(hedychium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedychium) be eaten?

The rhizomes look and smell exactly like the ginger in grocery stores.

Answer (score 1):

If it is *Hedychium coronarium* it seems that it is not toxic so it shouldn't be immediately deadly. While young leaves and flowers are eaten as famine food the rhizomes are only used as folk medicine which I interpret to mean that they taste of socks and have the texture of rotten wood.

I think it mainly boils down to whether you are using toxic pesticides and/or fertilizers to grow it.

I still would be wary of eating much of a species that hasn't been extensively consumed by humans in the last century.